# Include previous N rows of filter matches

Tags: python, pandas

I have a log file loaded into data frame. I would like to filter this log to get the rows where the log level is "error" and also include the previous N rows leading up to that error.

Log data frame:

```
    Level
=========
1   info 
2   info 
3   info
4   error
5   info 
6   info 
7   info
8   error
```

Desired result after filtering by error and including previous 2 rows

```
    Level
=========
2   info 
3   info
4   error
6   info 
7   info
8   error
```

I tried to add the previous values to each row by doing the following:

```py
pd['prev_level_1'] = pd['Level'].shift(1)
pd['prev_level_2'] = pd['Level'].shift(2)
pd['prev_level_3'] = pd['Level'].shift(3)
pd['prev_level_4'] = pd['Level'].shift(4)
```

From which I could then run the filter. But this approach seems convoluted and I also get the following error:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
```

What would be the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```
df.groupby(df.loc[::-1,'Level'].eq('error').cumsum()[::-1]).tail(3)
```

Output:

```
   Level
2   info
3   info
4  error
6   info
7   info
8  error
```